# fgets() and sscanf() only stores first integer in array

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I was trying to terminate Integer array input using Enter key. So, I thought of using fgets and sscanf() but I have tried several approaches everytime i am getting first value only. Can someone help where I am doing wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int inp[100]={0};

int c=0,n;
char str[100]={0};
char *data = str;

while ((NULL != fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) && (str[0] != '\n')) {
    if (1 != sscanf(str,"%d",&inp[c])) {
        puts("Input was not an integer, try again.\n");
        continue;
    }
    printf("\ninp[%d] = %d",c,inp[c]);
    c++;
    if (c >= 100) break;
}
}
```

I have added snap of my code and output - 
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcvCk.jpg)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnxJD.jpg)

Comment: Not able to reproduce your problem. Can you share your input/output?

Comment: @kiranBiradar I have added screenshots in question. If that helps.

Comment: `fgets` gets a line from a stream, a line needs to end with a newline to allow subsequent reads. So type in a character, followed by a newline

Comment: @chux I was trying to put the integers from that array in an integer array.

Answer (score 2):

`%n` is to capture the how many bytes have been read, thus you need to increment `data` `n` bytes to point to next number.

The below program reads all the integers till empty new line.

```
int main() {
  int inp[100] = {0};

  int c = 0, n = 0;
  char str[100] = {0};
  char *data = str;

  while ((NULL != fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) && (str[0] != '\n')) {
    data = str;
    n = 0;
    while (1 == sscanf(data, "%d%n", &inp[c], &n) && c < 100) {
      printf("\ninp[%d] = %d\n", c, inp[c]);
      data += n;
      c++;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. But can you please explain the code. What `%n` does. and why chose `data` and increment it.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass hitting enter key again after end of loop. I have other functions and operations after the loop. But when running this I have to press enter twice to get out of loop.